# Condensing this jquery to one script

Tags: jquery

We are building a responsive site at the moment with a grid of divs with sliding content reveals.  I have had some success with the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner-two").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper-two").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner-two").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner-two").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner-three").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper-three").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner-three").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner-three").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner-four").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper-four").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner-four").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner-four").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner-five").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper-five").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner-five").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner-five").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = $(".inner-seven").width();
var toggle = true;
$(".wrapper-seven").click(function(){
    if(toggle) {
        $(".inner-seven").stop().animate({left:0},1000);
    } else {
        $(".inner-seven").stop().animate({left:-width},1000);
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
});
});
</script>
```

As you can see i dont have a great deal of jquery understanding, so im sure there is a better way to write this rather than in the method undertaken.  I was hoping somehow out there could either give me some pointers or rewrite the script to be more like an array instead of an ugly repetitive list of the same code with different ids and classes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Can post a fiddle if that helps.

Comment: So you don't know how to deal with arrays as well?

Comment: nope jquery noob here

Comment: it's a jquery-irrelevent issue: create an array `['inner', 'inner-two', ...]` and run the single method that uses array items as a parameter

Comment: thanks will look into arrays, this should help? - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Answer (score 0):

Move everything in each `$(document).ready()` into a single `$(document).ready()` block. Use a multiple selector to select all the different elements instead of 7.

Comment: so just remove the following between each block?, this leads to some errors in the way the slider slides that were not occurring before. 


});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){